# What steps are airlines taking to retain and acquire pilots?

Tags: airline-operations, airline-pilot

It's well known that there's a global commercial pilot shortage, likely due to the cost of becoming a pilot, as well as the lackluster starting salaries. I've heard that airlines are making pushes to acquire new pilots, as well as retain current ones, but **what steps are they taking to accomplish this?**

Please link to sources if you can.

Comment: Take a look at what [Lufthansa does for pilot training](https://www.european-flight-academy.com/en/your-flying_future/fees_and_financing), a similar program is offered by a number of different airlines...

Comment: It's not the cost.  Learning to fly has always been an expensive pastime (a new C-172  was the price of a nice house in the 60s) and the difficulty in getting a career started was WAY worse 30 years ago.  The main factor is demographics.  The baby boom wave is hitting retirement age and the pool of potential new pilots is getting smaller and smaller.

Comment: @JohnK Learning to fly has always been an expensive pastime, but recently it has become more expensive. The FAA has increased hours requirements, flight requirements, and criteria for credible hours. The aircraft have also gotten more expensive to fly. Plus, new 172's are still the cost of a nice house today (well above the median home price in US).

Comment: Well yes what you are talking about is the Colgan rule, which was a fiasco but that only affects the US and its effect is to keep new pilots with the 3rd tier carriers longer until they get to 1500 hrs.  It had a negative effect on Regional airline recruiting in the US. Most other western countries also have a shortage, and it's mostly related to the demographic wave I mentioned.

Comment: @JohnK Quite a lot of articles and studies would disagree with you. The demographic issue does *effect* it, but to say that cost is not a factor is unequivocally false.

Comment: These days it's about 50k to get to a Comm with a Group 1 IFR.  That's in much more expensive Canada.  That's about 10k in 1975 in constant dollars.  10k was about what it was going to cost me to get to the same place in 1975, so I stopped at Private until much later.   It WASN'T cheaper in some halcyon old time.  To the extent that training requirements are more compared to long ago, yes there is a difference, but way less than the fact that the potential pilot pool is very small today.  When I came of age in the 70s I had massive competition from all my mid BB wave compatriots.  That's gone.

Comment: Standard minimum cost quoted by flight schools is 70k in USD. Costs vary by sources, but in the 60's/70's, it seems to roughly hover around 7-15k USD, and when adjusted by year, still shows a roughly 55% cost increase. On top of that, there were many pilots coming out of the military at that time who had much lower commercial training costs due to their experience, meaning the overall costs were even lower.

Comment: There ya go... 50k... http://flaviationacademy.com/become-a-commercial-pilot-1/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA8f_eBRDcARIsAEKwRGe0VaOMbI_dokXjzwchbCyJhD5SJfTowNil7f39OvEZKYlImcvDLNwaAogFEALw_wcB   70k is at one of those comprehensive colleges.

Comment: @JohnK That includes 247 hours for your commercial single/multi license. That doesn't involve getting to the 1500 hour mark to be able to fly for an airline.

Comment: 1500 hours would cost a quarter million! Nobody on a career path pays for that out of pocket.  Nobody.  You get a lower level job and work it up.  Guys were going to the Regionals, in many cases, right from those schools with 250hrs until the Colgan Rule.  Now they have no choice but to take the lower tier job instructing or flying a 1900 or something until they get to 1500.  Fact is though, this is the BEST time ever to be trying to get a flying career going.  Without question.